# Migrate from Ubercart 3 to Commerce

Tags: commerce, migrations

I have been trying to understand how to accomplish this for quite some time.  And I'm not getting anywhere. The info I'm finding seems a bit dated.

Can anyone tell me where to start to get this accomplished?

I am looking to migrate only products.  Nothing else.  The new site will be a fresh start other than product/inventory.  And with some 1500 products, I really need a migration process.

Is there a template for Commerce Ubercart Migration that I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably easier to query and dump results to a CSV file, and use that as the data source in the migration?

Comment: Have you looked into [Commerce migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) it has support for importing from ubercart.

Comment: I have.  I installed it.  But have no clue where to start.  I have found videos that are more than a couple of years old and not relevant.  And it seems that all I am finding in docs is not helping me understand how to do this.  So I am starting to feel that this is just beyond my ability.

Answer (score 3):

Our official migration path lives in [Commerce Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) and contains migrations for Commerce 1.x, Ubercart 2.x (D6) and Ubercart 3.x (D7). Improvements are released monthly.

Comment: Is there any recent documentation on this?  I haven't found anything that explains how to get there from here, as it were.

Comment: The module has its own docs at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/commerce-migrate